# Combine table and views in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking into extract table name and all related views and schemas in my SQL Server.

Until now I have used this SQL code to do that:

```
SELECT
    t.VIEW_SCHEMA, 
    t.VIEW_NAME, 
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    t.TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE t
WHERE
    t.TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
    AND t.VIEW_NAME like '%_something%'
```

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE` seems only to be updated when views actually are used, so when I run my code on a table with have new view definitions or a views has never been used it returns nothing.

I have tried to combine `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` but I can't find a key to join on.

I have also tried to look into `sys.tables` and `sys.views` but I still haven't found a way to join it.

I really need to get the columns specified in SQL.

Any ideas on how to do that? Maybe my approach is all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server offers a few possibilities via `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` and `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities()`

`sys.sql_expression_dependencies` is easier to use, an example for your purpose would be

```
select 
    Schema_Name(v.schema_id) View_Schema, v.name View_Name, 
    Schema_Name(t.schema_id) Table_Schema, t.name Table_Name
from sys.tables t
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d on d.referenced_id=t.object_id
join sys.objects v on v.object_id=d.referencing_id and v.type='V'
where 
  t.name='tablename' 
  and v.name like '%something%'
```